# Wrong output when searching for prime numbers in given interval

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to find to find prime numbers between `num1` and `num2`, but this code is yields only 1,2,3 as prime numbers if my input is 1,10

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void prime(int num1, int num2)
{
    bool prime = 1; // prime=1 means the number is prime
    for (num1; num1 <= num2; num1++)
    {
        for (int i = 2; i < num1; i++)
        {
            if (num1 % i == 0)
            {
                prime = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (prime == 0)
        {
            cout << num1 << " Is not Prime" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << num1 << " Is prime" << endl;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int num1, num2;
    cout << "Enter 2 numbers to check the prime numbers between them:";
    cin >> num1 >> num2;
    prime(num1, num2);
}
```

Comment: *Please fix my code* is not an acceptable question here. What does the debugger show you when you step through the code? If you don't know how to use it, learn now. You can figure out this sort of problem yourself in the future, and learn a lot about how your code is working in the process.

Comment: 1 is not prime, by definition. But it doesn't have any factors >= 2 so your code thinks it is prime.

Comment: Off topic: research prime number sieves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting `prime=1` only once, before you start looping over candidate prime numbers. So as soon as you hit a number that isn't prime (in your case, 4) you get `prime=0` and after that it never gets set to 1 again.

Answer (score 0):

Also second **for** should go from 3 to **(int)sqrt((double)num2)**, with a step **i+=2**.

Comment: That will make the code more *efficient* but not more *correct*. (Er, actually it will make it less correct, but I take it you meant `num1` rather than `num2`!)

Comment: Neither of those two casts is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting to reset bool prime to true.

Try this....

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void prime(int num1, int num2)
{
    for (num1; num1 <= num2; num1++)
    {    
        bool prime = 1; // prime=1 means the number is prime
        for (int i = 2; i < num1; i++)
        {
            if (num1 % i == 0)
            {
                prime = 0;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (prime == 0)
            cout << num1 << " Is not Prime" << endl;
        else
            cout << num1 << " Is prime" << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int num1, num2;
    cout << "Enter 2 numbers to check the prime numbers between them:";
    cin >> num1 >> num2;
    prime(num1, num2);
}
```